# Functional Unit and Micro-operations Schematics

Tags: circuits, sequential-circuit

I'm sitting an exam on Computer Architecture in a few days and i'm stuck on a particular type of question.

I'm asked to:

**Provide a detailed schematic for a functional unti that implements the following micro-operations**

[image]

Any help would be great even just a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: Some of the FS bits are going to control several muxes that will mux between the  adder, an "and", an "or", an "xor", the "not" and the shifters.  You're going to need to be able to control the carry-in of the adder, and you'll need to be able to negate the B input.  Then it's "just" a matter of mapping the FS bits to the mux inputs, to the carry-in, to the B negater and to the shifteer.  Note that they've tried to make it slightly easier by making the left two bits of FS determine whether you are using the adder, shifter or "logic" unit.

Comment: @WanderingLogic The encoding also has the nice feature that for the FS=00xxx, bit 0 (least significant) is the carry-in, bit 2 determines whether the second operand is inverted, and bit 2 XOR bit 1 determines whether the second operand is 0 or B. (Note: A-1 = A + NOT(0) and A = A + NOT(0)+1) [I thought I left a comment with this information earlier, but perhaps I did not actually submit the comment.]

Comment: Doh! The question was asked on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412759/functional-unit-and-micro-operations-schematics) and I left my comment there. Sigh--time for bed!

Comment: thanks guys does anybody know where I could get a sample schematic, not the answer just something similar?

Comment: As a general rule, we don't like to just answer homework or exam problems because we don't think that helps you. Please share with us what you have tried so we can identify and address your problems. (Also, please get rid of the horrible image and typeset the values properly.)

Comment: I'm not looking for the answer, I just need some guidance, what kind of schematic is needed?, I don't have time to be typing that out